# Do app domains communicate faster than windows services

Tags: .net, windows-services, soa, appdomain, remoting

Consider a SOA design implemented in .NET running on the same machine, where dynamically switching off, unloading, loading and restarting components is obligatory. (The efficiency of this procedure is not part of the question).

Of two options : Multiple Windows Services or Multiple AppDomains "in a" default AppDomain, taking into account the fastest possible communication channels in both scenario´s, when it comes to communication speed: Is there any difference?

Comment: Why are you asking us? [Go race your horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)!

Comment: because I would like some people more clever than myself guide me in what horse I might decide to give a test ride first, as there might be subtleties in the .NET remoting / WCF I´m unaware of.

Comment: Some of the things the article brings up directly applies to your question, in particular the "Do you really need to answer that question?" paragraph and the "Is the difference relevant?" paragraph. If you test it you may find both methods are fast enough to meet the goals you have for your performance, then you can just choose the one that you are most comfortable programming for. Using a tech you are familiar and conferrable with will lead to less bugs and maintenance in the future for the program.

Comment: Sorry.. I was hoping to spare one of the horses if the result was obvious. In particular "If someone had an answer to that question" I could probably save myself a ton of work.. Setting up test environments for multiple communicating windows services / appdomains is not a trivial task for all of us. Please feel free to delete the post if inappropriate

Comment: IMHO I think it is going to be pretty close. Honestly, if I thought there would have been a obvious winner I would have posted an answer instead of the comment. I only post that comment on questions where I have a strong feeling that the two options are going to only be marginally different in speed.

Comment: Thanks.. That answers the question and was also my immediate ( but non informed ) guess..  If you create an answer stating the difference will be insignificant I´ll mark it as the answer and start investigating other aspects. Communication speed was just my primary concern, but as you and the blog post indicate : The bottleneck is likely to be some where else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge the difference in speed between the two methods will be minor. The only way to tell which will out perform the other is do a real world test on a machine configured like your production environment and compare them.

Most likely you will find the RPC method you use will not be the bottleneck but something else will be instead.